# How to find maximum and minimum temeprature?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

There was a problem regarding an outside temperature varying as a sine wave, after solving the ODE I got a function, which I later on differentiated to get the maximum and minimum temperature, however I need to figure out $t_{max}$ and $t_{min}$, this is what I got after differentitating:

$$\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12} \right)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$

However I am not sure how can I find the maximum and minimum $t$ here?

The original equation is:

$$T(t)=65-\dfrac{540}{36+\pi^{2}}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12}\right)-\dfrac{90\pi}{36+\pi^{2}}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12} \right)
$$

Comment: Presumably you want to find the roots to this equation, though without seeing how you got here it is a guess.  Take the arctangent of both sides and note that you need to add an arbitrary multiple of $\pi$

Comment: Would you mind showing your original equation? If the temperature varies like a sine wave, the derivative should be cosine, not tangent

Comment: @Andrei I edited my question now and added the original equation.

Comment: Your $T(t)$ is a function of time, it does not make sense to find $t_{max}$. Do you mean $T_{max}$?

Comment: @Vasya In the solution manual, they took the derivative of T(t), where T'(t)=0, they later on evaluated $t_{max}$ and $t_{min}$ to substitute  back in to get the $T_{max}$ and $T_{min}$. But I have no idea how they did it.

Comment: So they calculate the first derivative and equate it to 0, like you do. I get $t=\frac{12}{\pi}(\arctan\frac{\pi}{6}+k\pi)$, where $k$ is any integer. You can calculate the second derivative, and you see that for $k=0$ the second derivative is positive, so we have a minimum and at $k=1$ you have a maximum. Just plug those times back into your original formula for $T(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $$\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12} \right)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$ has many solutions.

Let  $$ \alpha = \dfrac{\pi t}{12}$$

One solution  to $tan (\alpha )= \pi/6$ is $\alpha = \tan ^{-1} (\pi /6)$ where $\alpha$ is in the first quadrant, which makes both $\sin (\alpha)$ and $\cos (\alpha )$ to be positive.

For this value of $\alpha $ we find $$t=\frac {12\alpha}{\pi }$$ is a minimizer of $T(t)$ because we are subtracting positive values from $65$

Thus  $$t_{min} = \frac {12\alpha }{\pi}.$$

To find the maximizer we choose $\beta = \pi + \alpha$, where both $\sin (\beta )$ and $\cos (\beta )$ are negative.

Thus $$t_{max} = \frac {12\beta }{\pi}.$$